# Object is not callable the second time I call a class method

Tags: python

I have a class Match:

```
class Match(object):

  def __init__(self,id):
      self.id = id

  def result(self):
      # somehow find the game result
      self.result = result
      return self.result
```

If I initialize a match object as

```
m = Match(1)
```

when I call the method result I get

```
m.result
Out[18]: <bound method Match.result of <football_uk.Match object at 0x000000000B0081D0>>
```

When I call it with the parenthesis, I get

```
m.result()
Out[19]: u'2-3'
```

That is the correct answer. However, when I try to call a second, third, fourth, etc. time the method, I get

```
m.result()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-42f6486e36a5>", line 1, in <module>
m.result()

TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

If instead now I call the method without the parenthesis, it works:

```
m.result
Out[21]: u'2-3'
```

The same with other similar methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have given your instance an attribute named `result`:

```
self.result = result
```

This now masks the method. You can't use the same name as the method if you don't want it masked. Rename the attribute or the method.

You could use the name `_result` for example:

```
def result(self):
    # somehow find the game result
    self._result = result
    return self._result
```

`self` is just another reference to the same object that `m` references. Attributes set or found on `self` are the same ones that you can find on `m`, because they are the same object. There is no difference between `m.result` and `self.result` here.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you!